# Number of columns in the data does not match the number of columns in the range

Tags: google-apps-script

I know this issue has been posted about quite a few times but I'm still struggling to make it work.  I have the code below:

```
function conditionalFormat (subGradeRange, colourRange, colourRangeVals) {
  
  subGradeRange.setBorder(true, true, true, true, true, true);
  subDash.setColumnWidths(11, 11, 40)
  subDash.setColumnWidth(10, 70);
  subDash.setColumnWidths(22, 4, 80);
  subGradeRange.setHorizontalAlignment("center");

  var colours = [];

  for (var i = 1; i < colourRangeVals.length; i++) {
    colours[i] = [];
    for (var j = 0; j < colourRangeVals[i].length; j++) {

      var avgTarget = subDash.getRange("O1").getValue();
      var gradeCell = subDash.getRange(3, j + 12).getValue();
      var avgTargetCell = subSheetPP.getRange(i + 1, 17).getValue();
      var mockGradeCell = subDash.getRange(i + 3, j + 12);
      var mockGradeCellVal = mockGradeCell.getValue();
      
      if (avgTarget == 0 && gradeCell > avgTargetCell && mockGradeCellVal >= 0) {
        colours[i][j] = "#dabeec";
      } else if (avgTarget == -1 && gradeCell > avgTargetCell -1 && mockGradeCellVal >= 0) {
        colours[i][j] = "#dabeec";
      } else if (avgTarget == -2 && gradeCell > avgTargetCell - 2 && mockGradeCellVal >= 0) {
        colours[i][j] = "#dabeec";
      } else if (avgTarget == 0 && gradeCell == avgTargetCell && mockGradeCellVal >= 0) {
        colours [i][j] = "#b8dac1";
      }  else if (avgTarget == -1 && gradeCell == avgTargetCell -1 && mockGradeCellVal >= 0) {
        colours [i][j] = "#b8dac1";
      }  else if (avgTarget == -2 && gradeCell == avgTargetCell - 2 && mockGradeCellVal >= 0) {
        colours [i][j] = "#b8dac1";
      } else if (avgTarget == 0 && gradeCell < avgTargetCell && mockGradeCellVal >= 0) {
        colours [i][j] = "#e7b3b3";
      } else if (avgTarget == -1 && gradeCell < avgTargetCell - 1 && mockGradeCellVal >= 0) {
        colours [i][j] = "#e7b3b3";
      } else if (avgTarget == -2 && gradeCell < avgTargetCell - 2 && mockGradeCellVal >= 0) {
        colours [i][j] = "#e7b3b3";
      } else {
        colours [i][j] = 'white';
      }
    }
  }
  Logger.log("done");
  colourRange.setBackgrounds(colours);
}
```

When debugging my colourRangeVals has an array of 31 with 10 columns.  My colours array has an array of 31 with 10 columns but I still get the above error.

Any ideas??

Thanks

Comment: If you will manage to make your code reproducible it will increase the prospects to get a useful answer.

Answer (score 1):

The issue may be caused by the first `for` loop that starts iteration from 1 instead of 0.

To see the results in the spreadsheet and so make debugging easier, try replacing the last line of code with this:

`colourRange.offset(0, 0, colours.length, colours[0].length).setBackgrounds(colours);`

Comment: The colourRange.offset gave an error message but changing the i to equal 0 instead of 1 worked!  Thanks a ton :)